# Inlining repeated calls (GHC)

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc, inlining

Will GHC inline a function that is used more than once? For example:

```
{-# INLINE innerLoop #-}
innerLoop x = stuff...

g f = 
    f 0 + f 1 + f 2
```

If we call `g innerLoop` will the function `innerLoop` be duplicated three times? Or will it just became `g stuff...`?

How can we either force `innerLoop` to be inlined multiple times or prevent it from being inlined multiple times?

Comment: I'd inline `g` as well. Also, check the GHC Core output to see what's going on. And most importantly, profile everything to check this inlining really matters.